# Resetting other select boxes when any one is selected

Tags: jquery, wordpress, select

Resetting all other select menus when any one is selected (jQuery and Wordpress)

I need all other select menus to be reset (without hitting submit) when any one is selected. Here is an example with just two menus but I will probably need it to work with four. (select one, other three are reset to default values)

Example menu 1 :

```
    <select name="jj_register_options[number]" id="jj_register_options[number]">
    <option value="">Front Page</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1115">Cart</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1143">Checkout</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="1148">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Checkout → Pay</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="1149">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Order Received</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1009">Checkout</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1116">Image Store</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="971">Logout</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="967">Lost Password</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1042">Members</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1144">My Account</option>
</select>
```

Example menu 2

```
<select name="jj_register_options[categories]" id="jj_register_options[categories]" class="">
    <option class="level-0" value="1">Uncategorized&nbsp;&nbsp;(0)</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="5">testy test&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="7">Help &amp; Support&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="8">Themes&nbsp;&nbsp;(0)</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="24">Entertainment&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="28">Lifestyle&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)</option>
</select>
```

When one is clicked the other needs to reset.

I have this code but it is not working.

```
$('#jj_register_options[number]').change(function(){
    $('#jj_register_options[categories]').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});

$('#jj_register_options[categories]').change(function(){
    $('#jj_register_options[number]').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am good with PHP, but have almost no jQuery / javascript knowledge,

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses `[` and `]` for attribute selectors, your selector selects an element with ID of `jj_register_options` that has `categories` attribute. Escape them or use different identifiers. the `.prop()` method will work as it is if you are using jQuery 1.6+.

```
(function($) {
   $(function() {
      $('#jj_register_options\\[categories\\]').on('change', function() {
          // ...
      }); 
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This actually is not jQuery specific but CSS specific.

Comment: @hakre Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to brasofilo and Harke for the answer.
PLease see the jquery code used for reference. This was used in conjunction with three separate select boxes with ids 'jj_register_cats' , 'jj_register_tag' and 'jj_register_page'. Note I have included jQuery rather than $ as this is how wordpress likes it;-) Thanks again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {   
jQuery('#jj_register_page').change(function(){
    jQuery('#jj_register_cats').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    jQuery('#jj_register_tag').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});

jQuery('#jj_register_cats').change(function(){
    jQuery('#jj_register_page').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    jQuery('#jj_register_tag').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});

jQuery('#jj_register_tag').change(function(){
    jQuery('#jj_register_page').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    jQuery('#jj_register_cats').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The `id` doesn't have to follow the `option[key]` format, as the form processing is based on `name` not `id`.

```
<select name="jj_register_options[number]" id="jj_number">
<select name="jj_register_options[categories]" id="jj_categories" class="">
```

It's easier and cleaner to target them this way.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    $('#jj_number').change(function(){
        $('#jj_categories').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    });

    $('#jj_categories').change(function(){
        $('#jj_number').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks. I have changed the ids but I am still not getting the behaviour I want. Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Updated the answer with the jQuery wrapper. I tested your code with this JS and worked ok.

Comment: This works perfectly now. I had to change the $ to jQuery (wordpress is a bit funny like that). Many thanks ;-)